# OData with associated objects but not inline

Tags: odata, associated-object

I am trying to understand OData...

I know the $expand parameter and it is nearly what I need but:
The returned, embedded data is highly redundant.

This leads me to the question: How can I get the associated objects as references AND a separate list of the referenced objects in one call?

Or is there something important I did not understand yet?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by redundant. Please provide some code samples to show your data model and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Are you trying to access the associated objects directly? If so, you can access it as a normal property. For example: http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Products(1)/ProductDetail, ProductDetail is a navigation property of product